# Creating a file dynamically through jsp

Tags: java, jsp, io

I have a block of jsp code like this. Here blockerdata, criticaldata, majordata and minordata are stringbuilder strings and their value is appended through a loop and value is assigned dynamically. Now I'm tryong to write them into an xml file like this.

```
<%
        System.out.println(blockerdata);
        System.out.println(criticaldata);
        System.out.println(majordata);
        System.out.println(minordata);
        try
        {

            File file1 = new File("WebContent/criticaldata.xml");
            File file2 = new File("WebContent/majordata.xml");
            File file3 = new File("WebContent/minordata.xml");
            File file4 = new File("WebContent/blockerdata.xml");

            FileOutputStream fop1 = new FileOutputStream(file1);
            FileOutputStream fop2 = new FileOutputStream(file2);
            FileOutputStream fop3 = new FileOutputStream(file3);
            FileOutputStream fop4 = new FileOutputStream(file4);


            // if file doesnt exists, then create it
            if (!file1.exists()) {
                file1.createNewFile();
            }
            if (!file2.exists()) {
                file2.createNewFile();
            }
            if (!file3.exists()) {
                file3.createNewFile();
            }
            if (!file4.exists()) {
                file4.createNewFile();
            }

            // get the content in bytes
            byte[] contentInBytes1= criticaldata.toString().getBytes();
            byte[] contentInBytes2= majordata.toString().getBytes();
            byte[] contentInBytes3= minordata.toString().getBytes();
            byte[] contentInBytes4= blockerdata.toString().getBytes();

            fop1.write(contentInBytes1);
            fop2.write(contentInBytes1);
            fop3.write(contentInBytes1);
            fop4.write(contentInBytes1);

            fop1.flush();
            fop2.flush();
            fop3.flush();
            fop4.flush();

            fop1.close();
            fop2.close();
            fop3.close();
            fop4.close();

        }
        catch ( IOException e)
        {
        }
        %>
```

Problem is, the code doesn't seem to be working. I tried to do it using printwriter also but
the files are not being generated. Also I want to rewrite the file if it already exists. Can somebody please help me on how to do this ?

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: No error at all. Just the files are not getting created

Comment: 1) Include exception printing in yours catch block; 2) maybe, you are searching in wrong directory, possible, files created not in webapp directory, but in Tomcat root directory.

Comment: 1. I'm using JBoss in eclipse. 2. The files aren't being created there also.

Comment: @Karthik do one thing put  this line System.out.println(file1.getAbsolutePath()); after     File file1 = new File("WebContent/criticaldata.xml"); , and then check the log (console)of Jboss server..Then then you will come to know where they are getting created.

Comment: No need. @pasha701 was right. They were getting created in the jboss root folder only. I changed the path then I got the required result